# ANOSIM in Vegan is not working

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to perform an **anosim** analysis in **Vegan**, but it doesn't seem to work... It doesn't give an error after the anosim function, but when I try to see the summary it says:

> Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
>   'x' must be atomic

My data looks like a simple community matrix with sites and species (identical to the Dune data set).

I've tried this:

```
dist.com <- vegdist(data, method = "bray")
an = anosim(dist.com, env)
summary(an)
```

The class of `data` is a **data.frame** , the class of `env` is **factor** and the class of `dist.com` is **dist**.

It is identical to the example in help...

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing reproducible here, but I can generate this error message if the factor has only one level:

`summary(anosim(vegdist(dune), rep("a",  nrow(dune))))`